# How to limit the total width of auto-fill or auto-fit columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to limit how wide a CSS Grid with Auto-Fit and Auto-Fill can go, without affecting the responsiveness of it?  Or, is there a better method to use?

Using the CSS below, I have 7 controls that all fit on one row, I'd like to split that into two rows without affecting the responsiveness, the idea being if I limit how wide the auto-fit rows can go.

I've tried using 'width: px', but that breaks the responsiveness.

**Code for one section:**

```css
.Search {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
    align-items: end;
}
```

I can break it into multiple html sections, but that leaves a gap.

**Code for multiple sections:**

```css
.Search, .SchoolID {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
    align-items: end;    
}
```

**Screenshot with multiple sections.**

At a certain screen resolution, row 2 column 2 is blank because the next item begins in a different section.  All other resolutions are fine with multiple sections, but I would like to account for this resolution as well.  I'd rather be able to account for this without using multiple html sections if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `max-width` value to your code to resolve this issue.